# Excel automation integrated with Cucumber framework

Tags: java, excel, maven, cucumber, apache-poi

How possibly can I implement auto-driven Excel file in my cucumber framework?
It is worth mentioning that I am using Maven and Apache POI dependency to handle Excel file.

What I would like to do with the Excel file? I want to first read data cell by cell from Excel, compare them with a similar chart I have in one of my .feature file and update the feature file accordingly. The process might be the other way around.

To run my test suit I use this line in my command line to fire up Maven:
mvn clean test -Denv="dev" -Dtestsuite="single/dsk_chrome" -Dcucumber.options="--tags @test"

Please give me a general idea where can I start and how.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to update your feature file programmatically.
You might be better off just running your tests directly from Excel with Apache POI?